# Get the average rating for each object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scopes

Probably a simple question for most, but still getting to grips with Database queries. I have recipes that can be given a rating, I now want to collect those ratings and get the average rating. A recipe has many ratings  (I think this is the correct relationship)

I have created a scope like so

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :ratings
attr_accessible :country, :description, :name
scope :average_rating,includes(:ratings).group('recipe_id').where('AVG(ratings.rating)');
end
```

ratings model

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users
attr_accessible :ratings, :recipe_id, :user_id
end
```

Should my ratings also include has_many :recipes ?

In my controller i have created an instance variable to display the result

```
@avgrating = Recipe.average_rating
```

but stuck on how to get this to show in my view within this block for example within my index which the controller is simply

```
 @recipes = Recipe.all
```

and the view

```
<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
<tr>
<td><%= recipe.name %></td>
<td><%= recipe.description %></td>
<td><%= recipe.country %></td>
<td>Avg Rating =<%= not sure here %></td>
</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Im sure ill feel silly when i see the answer but just cant think how to do it right now

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `<td>Avg Rating =<%= recipe.ratings.average(:ratings) %></td>`

Comment: so no need for a scope here then? over complicating things? getting undefined method avg now

Comment: yep no need for a scope. and that should be `average`, not `avg`. sorry!

Comment: yup brilliant, works, im assuming i can add to this now and round the numbers up or down, as at the moment getting results like 4.2

Comment: yep. just append `.round(2)` or `.ceil` or `.floor`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  recipe.ratings.average(:ratings)
```

or

```
  <% ratings = recipe.ratings %>
  <%= ratings.map(&:ratings).sum/ratings.count %>
```